# Create and return a vector of strings - most efficient solution?

Tags: c++, vector, construct

In a member function, I want to return a newly created vector of strings.
Which version is the most efficient from a memory allocation & constructor calling point of view? `theString(i)` returns a `const std::string &`

```
std::vector<std::string> result(depth());
for(int i=0;i<depth;i++) {
    result[i] = theString(i);
}
```

or

```
std::vector<std::string> result;
result.reserve(depth());
for(int i=0;i<depth;i++) {
    result.emplace_back(theString(i));
}
```

To me it seems that:

- Solution 1 constructs every empty string first, then copy-assigns them => not perfect
- Solution 2 is better since it will copy-construct every string, while the vector data is allocated once by `reserve`

(or is there an even more efficient solution?)

Comment: which code snippet is easier to maintain, or to ignore when hunting for a bug, so on

Comment: I would imagine that your compiler would optimize both to the same code, check the assembly output for both and see if there are any differences. As Alf mentioned, readability is far more important than these micro optimizations though. So go with whatever is easiest to read and maintain.

Comment: Well, there is no much difference in readability, and it's definitely in a speed critical section.

Comment: [The Rules of Optimization Club](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=962631) Apply the second rule.

Comment: @shuttle87: actually, that's pretty unlikely. But whether it makes a difference in speed is another question.

Comment: @MatthieuM, I just looked up `emplace_back` and it is a bit different to what I thought. So yes it might be different code produced. Given that it's in a speed critical section I would imagine that profiling the code is the best way to go.

Comment: The best thing would be to have theString() take a vector as additional argument and construct the string via emplace_back directly in the vector. That would avoid the copy that needs to happen in any case, unless you have the vector hold references or pointers. It's not a far jump to make the collection a template argument to support lists etc. as well.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: actually, I would be surprised if it improved things. out-parameters were never really useful in C++ to start with, and they are even less now that we have move semantics.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Will the string whose reference is returned by theString(i) indeed be moved if theString(i) returns just a const &? Btw, I meant a vector **ref** or pointer as additional argument, of course.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: no, a copy must occur. Which is no different than if `std::vector<std::string>&` was passed to `theString` I suppose, because it must return a `const&` to something that already exists anything.

Comment: Is there any chance you could tell us how that `std::vector<std::string>` is used ? Because of course the most efficient way would be not to create the `vector` in the first place.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thought it could be a factory.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to give a generic answer: depending on your compiler, the Standard Library implementation than you are using, the target CPU and the surrounding source code, the emitted code may vary. Furthermore, whether one solution or the other is faster may also be affected by cache effects or thread-switching effects caused by different scheduling.

So, unfortunately, there is no generic answer: measure with your setup.

That being said, let me offer two other candidates; candidate 3:

```
// The simplest code is always easier to read:
std::vector<std::string> result;
for (size_t i = 0; i < depth; ++i) { result.emplace_back(theString(i)); }
```

I would be surprised if it were much worse than your candidate 2. It relies on `vector`'s amortized constant `emplace_back` and the fact that moving strings is cheap (compared to copying).

And candidate 4:

```
// If no copy is necessary, then no copy is cheaper:
std::vector<std::string_view> result; // or another "StringRef" alternative
for (size_t i = 0; i < depth; ++i) { result.emplace_back(theString(i)); }
```

The latter relying on [`string_view`: a non-owning reference to a string](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3762.html) which is a very simply thing to implement (basically, a pair `size_t` and `char const*`) but is only viable if the referenced string is guaranteed to outlive the last use of the `string_view`.